# Handle Event before a Property Changes

Tags: c#

Is there an event handler that allows me to do something before a class' variable change value ? I only know about INotifyPropertyChanged/OnPropertyChanged, but that is after the value has been modified.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanging is the interface you looking for

Comment: Sounds like a dependency property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: On setter of your property, before setting value you can call NotifyPropertyChanged("PropertyName"), or If you are working with UI, you can take a look at Preview events, Preview events fires before value changes

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: Indeed, the de-facto way to do it. Write up an answer and I'll upvote.

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger: That makes two of us :)

Comment: Seems INotifyPropertyChanging doesn't stop the change event unless exception is thrown, but I guess that'll do... Compare to changing every Set Property, it's definitely easier.

Comment: @blue_lightning do you use WPF or Winforms?

Comment: WPF with MVVM, why ?

Comment: So you want to implement some validation?

Comment: There are so many ways it can be done. Are you working with a third-party class or one that you're writing?

Comment: Your question does not seem to hit your actual problem. Maybe you should rephrase and add some snippets of code...

Comment: Nah, actually I ask this question out of curiosity; currently I don't need it to stop the change. Just thought there ought to be an easy way to do this

Comment: they're mostly the same... but since you've already point out some problems in aush's code, guess I should pick precision over speed. Beside, using INotifyPropertyChanged before the change feels weird, somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for INotifyPropertyChanging:

```
public class AClass : INotifyPropertyChanging
{

    private int aField;

    public int AProperty
    {
        get { return aField; }
        set 
        {
            OnPropertyChanging("AProperty");
            aField = value; 
        }
    }


    private void OnPropertyChanging(string propertyName) 
    {
        PropertyChanging(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging = delegate { };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public event Action NotifyBeforeChanged;

    private int _value;
    public int Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            NotifyBeforeChanged();
            _value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to do a `null` check on `NotifyBeforeChanged` before calling it.

Comment: @Enigmativity, sure, it's just a simplified example to demonstrate the pattern. Also, it's better to implement it as a INotifyPropertyChanging to follow a common convention.

Comment: Another trick is to set it to an empty delegate... then its never null but does not do anything when raised...